# iOS UIPickerView Why Pickerview area is not removed after [pickerView removeFromSuperview];

Tags: ios, uipickerview

Why UIPickerView area is not removed after calling  [pickerView removeFromSuperview]?
The picker view is created in this code:

```
 UIPickerView *pickerAirport = [[UIPickerView alloc] init];
pickerAirport.tag=0;
pickerAirport.dataSource = self;
pickerAirport.delegate = self;
_Airport.inputView = pickerAirport;
```

The remove code is:

```
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component {
if (pickerView.tag == 0)
   {
    NSDictionary * ptr_airport=[self.AllairportsDictionary objectAtIndex:row];
    _Airport.text  =  ptr_airport[@"name"];
   }
else
     _State.text= ptr_aircraftState.StateAircraft[row];;
[pickerView removeFromSuperview];

self.view.center = originalCenter;   

}
```

Thanks

Comment: Do you know that the "else" part of your if-else statement is executed?

Comment: Yes, both are executed

Comment: Your code worked for me, but you might try having your text field resign first responder ([_Airport resignFirstResponder]), instead of using removeFromSuperview. That should cause the picker view to animate back off the screen.

Comment: Thanks rdelmar. It worked just fine. This is the solution.

Comment: rdelmar I have a similar problem with 3 pickers that are still responding after a pushed view is shown. Even when I do:

Comment: [_Datadovoo resignFirstResponder];
 [_AeroportoOrigem resignFirstResponder];
 [_AeroportoDestino resignFirstResponder];

Comment: [_Datadovoo resignFirstResponder];
        [_Datadovoo removeFromSuperview];
        [_AeroportoOrigem resignFirstResponder];
        [_AeroportoOrigem removeFromSuperview]; 
        [_AeroportoDestino resignFirstResponder];
        [_AeroportoDestino removeFromSuperview]; solved the problem